# How to texture paint only one part (normal map)?

Tags: materials, normals, texture-baking, texture-painting

Ok, Ive baked normals and there are some I want to get rid of completely - meaning go back to the purple color so they dont show up black. I dont need them and want them gone, but need them on other parts of the model. Right now I have my normal map fed into my material nodes, and I can see on my model where I want to remove normal "bumps" (where it isn't purple):

[image]

Trying to find where each "bump" is in photoshop isn't working. How can I mask OR paint over these "bumps" with texture paint? I tried painting over but they persisted. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of the viewport next to the pivot options is a toggle for face select masking in Texture Paint mode. Turn that on, and either in Edit mode select the faces that are the offenders here, or in Texture Paint use the rmb to select the faces. [image]You can sample the color from the normal map with the S key, and then paint it in masked by the face selection.